# In Blazor handle Blazor component InputNumber property readonly via code

Tags: input, blazor, readonly-attribute, blazor-component

```
<InputNumber readonly 
             id="ProductShares"
             class="form-control" 
             placeholder="Product Shares"
             oninput="@Calculation"
             @bind-Value="product.ProductShares" />
```

I want to update `InputNumber` to readonly in code. That is on event `oninput` I am calling `Calculation` method and I want to programmatically update `readonly` property.

```
public async void Calculation(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    // Something like
    if(condition)
    {
        ProductShares.readonly = true;  // ProductShares is the id of the InputNumber
    }
    else
    {
        ProductShares.readonly = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set bool value to readonly attribute like this

This is your html

```
<InputNumber readonly="@ReadOnly" 
             id="ProductShares"
             class="form-control" 
             placeholder="Product Shares"
             oninput="@Calculation"
             @bind-Value="product.ProductShares" />
```

This is your code behind

```
@code{
    private bool ReadOnly=true;
}
```